# Do content scripts still run if javascript is disabled on a site?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

If I disable javascript on a site using Chrome's javascript settings, does this prevent extensions from running [content scripts](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/content_scripts.html) on it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both content script and chrome.tabs.executeScript will run even if javascript is disabled.

But if your content script injects javascript in DOM, that injected javascript will not work.

Comment: Apparently, `setTimeout` in a content script does not work when JavaScript is disabled for the site, although the content script indeed still runs and, for instance, is able to receive image load events. (Using Chrome 56)

Answer (score 0):

No.  Content scripts are just javascript.  Any Javascript will be disabled by these settings.